# Multi parameter search via user input - ruby on rails & mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a web page where a user can search through documents in a mongoDB collection.
I get the user's input through `@q = params[:search].to_s`

I then run a mongoid query:
`@story = Story.any_of( { :Tags => /#{@q}/i}, {:Name => /#{@q}/i}, {:Genre => {/#{@q}/i}} )`

This works fine if the user looks for something like 'humor' 'romantic comedy' or 'mystery'. But if looking for 'romance fiction', nothing comes up. 
 Basically I'd like to add 'and' 'or' functionality to my search so that it will find documents in the database that are related to all strings that a user types into the input field.
How can this be done while still maintaining the substring search capabilties I currently have?
Thanks in advance for help!
**UPDATE:**
Per Eugene's comment below...
I tried converting to case insensitive with  `@q.map! { |x| x="/#{x}/i"}`. It does save it properly as `["/romantic/i","/comedy/i"]`. But the query `Story.any_of({:Tags.in => @q}, {:Story.in => @q})`finds nothing.
When I change the array to be `["Romantic","Comedy"]`. Then it does.
How can I properly make it case insensitive?

**Final:**
Removing the quotes worked. 
However there is now no way to use an `.and()` search to find a book that has both words in all these fields.

Comment: see my last comment. did that fix the issue?

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this two years later, you can make the AND request using just plain mongo syntax.  it would be something along the lines of:

query = { "$and" => [ {Tags: /romantic/i }, { Tags: /comedy/i ]   }

@story = Story.where(query)

The $and operator gets passed an array of objects that all have to match for the final result to match.  Looks ugly in Ruby, but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create an OR statement, you can convert the string into an array of strings, and then convert the array of strings into an array of regex and then use the '$in' option.  So first, pick a delimeter - perhaps commas or space or you can set up a custom like ||.  Let's say you do comma seperated.  When user enters:

romantic, comedy

you split that into `['romantic', 'comedy']`, then convert that to `[/romantic/i, /comedy/i]` then do

`@story = Story.any_of( { :Tags.in => [/romantic/i, /comedy/i]}....`

To create an AND query, it can get a little more complicated.  There is an elemMatch function you could use.

I don't think you could do `{:Tags => /romantic/i, :Tags => /comedy/i }`

So my best thought would be to do sequential queries, even though there would be a performance hit, but if your DB isn't that big, it shouldn't be a big issue.  So if you want Romantic AND Comedy you can do

query 1: find all collections that match /romantic/i

query 2: take results of query 1, find all collections that match /comedy/i

And so on by iterating through your array of selectors.

Comment: This helped a lot, but it still isn't properly searching case insensitive

Comment: get rid of the quotes in your regex.  

you want `[/romantic/i, /comedy/i]`  and not `["/romantic/i","/comedy/i"]`.

The way you have it, it's probably searching for a string rather than searching as a regular expression. you can map a string to a regex by doing `/#{string}/i`  without the quotes